# Subset of dataset based on variable start and end range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a very large dataset with the following columns: `id`, `date`, `val`. The `(id, date)` pair constitutes the unique key of the dataset. I have some thousands of ids, and for each of them I have data relative some thousands of dates.

I also have a support dataset, with the following columns: `id`, `start_date`, `end_date`. For each `id`, it tells what are the start date and end date we are interested in. Note that different ids will have different start and end dates.

I would like to retrieve a subset of the first dataset, which for each id only contains the dates in the range given by the support dataset.

My current solution in Python looks like this:

```py
ids = set(df["id"].to_list())
xs: List[pd.DataFrame] = []

for x in sids:
    start_end = date_ranges[date_ranges["id"] == x].iloc[0]
    first_date = start_end["start_date"]
    last_date = start_end["end_date"]

    new_df = df[
        df["id"] == x
        & (df["date"] >= first_date)
        & (df["date"] <= last_date)
    ]
    xs.append(new_df)

res = pd.concat(res)
```

However, having to do this for thousands of ids, it takes forever (almost a half hour) to generate the final DataFrame. I've been trying to figure out a faster way to do this, perhaps using `.groupby()`, but so far I couldn't come up with much. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to groupby:

```
# set the index for look up
date_ranges = date_ranges.set_index('id')

# start and end dates for each row
start_dates = df['id'].map(date_ranges['start_date'])
end_dates = df['id'].map(date_ranges['end_date'])

# filter
df.loc[df['date'].between(start_dates, end_dates)]
```

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang for your help. Indeed that works, but only if for each id there's a single `(start_date, end_date)` range. If the `date_ranges` dataframe contains the same id more than once, unfortunately this won't work. Instead, I'll get the following error:

`InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Do you know what can be done in that case?